# ARM - How can I get the access key from a storage account to use in AppSettings later in the template?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-resource-manager

I'm creating an Azure Resource Manager template that instantiates multiple resources, including an Azure storage account and an Azure App Service with a Web App.

I'd like to be able to capture the primary access key (or the full connection string, either way is fine) from the newly-created storage account, and use that as a value for one of the AppSettings for the Web App.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use the [listkeys](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-template-functions/#listkeys) helper function.

```
"appSettings": [
    {
      "name": "STORAGE_KEY",
      "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value]"
    }
]
```

This quickstart does something similar:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-web-app-arm-with-redis-cache-provision/

Comment: I added .key1 to your entry (that's the property that gets the primary access key), but this got me going. Thank you, and thanks to Emily as well.

Answer (score 45):

The syntax has changed since the other answer was accepted. The error you will now hit is `'Template language expression property 'key1' doesn't exist, available properties are 'keys'`

Keys are now represented as an array of keys, and the syntax is now:

```
"StorageAccount": "[Concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',variables('StorageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('StorageAccountName')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value)]",
```

See: http://samcogan.com/retrieve-azure-storage-key-in-arm-script/

Comment: To avoid being broken by this _and future_ changes, use a listKeys overload that accepts an api version. Like `listKeys(resourceId(...), '2015-05-01-preview').key1`

Answer (score 5):

I faced with this issue two times. First in the 2015 and last today in May of 2017.
I need to add connection strings to the WebApp - I want to add strings automatically from generated resources during deployment from the ARM template. It can help later to not add manually this values.

First time I used old version of the function listKeys (it looks like old version returns result not as object but as value):

```
"AzureWebJobsStorage": {
    "type": "Custom",
    "value": "[concat(variables('storageConnectionString'), listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), '2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
},
```

Today last version of the working template is:

```
"resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "type": "config",
      "name": "connectionstrings",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites/', parameters('webSiteName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "DefaultConnection": {
          "value": "[concat('Data Source=tcp:', reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('sqlserverName'))).fullyQualifiedDomainName, ',1433;Initial Catalog=', parameters('databaseName'), ';User Id=', parameters('administratorLogin'), '@', parameters('sqlserverName'), ';Password=', parameters('administratorLoginPassword'), ';')]",
          "type": "SQLServer"
        },
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": {
          "type": "Custom",
          "value": "[concat(variables('storageConnectionString'), listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageName')), '2016-01-01').keys[0].value)]"
        },
        "AzureWebJobsDashboard": {
          "type": "Custom",
          "value": "[concat(variables('storageConnectionString'), listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageName')), '2016-01-01').keys[0].value)]"
        }
      }
    },
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is link to documentation with function details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#listkeys

Answer (score 2):

below is example for adding storage account to ADLA

```
"storageAccounts": [
                  {
                    "name": "[parameters('DataLakeAnalyticsStorageAccountname')]",
                    "properties": {
                      "accessKey": "[listKeys(variables('storageAccountid'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1]"
                    }
                }
            ],
```

in variable you can keep

```
"variables": {
        "apiVersion": "[providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]]",
         "storageAccountid": "[concat(resourceGroup().id,'/providers/','Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('DataLakeAnalyticsStorageAccountname'))]"
    },
```