# Unable to get Azure storage key from storage resource in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-storage-account, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to build a connection string from a storage account used elsewhere in the template and I have

```
"StorageConnectionString": {
               "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',
 variables('storageName'),';AccountKey=',
 listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts',
 variables('storageName')), providers('Microsoft.Storage',
 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).key1)]",
              "type": "Custom"
             },
```

Which I found from [ARM - How can I get the access key from a storage account to use in AppSettings later in the template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225678/arm-how-can-i-get-the-access-key-from-a-storage-account-to-use-in-appsettings) however the syntax in that question no longer appears to work. I get an error that `key1` is not a property which is known. Apparently there is a property called `keys` but that is, as one might expect, a structure of some sort. I have been unable to figure out what the property of the primary key is from that structure. I've tried

- key1 -> Template language expression property 'key1' doesn't exist, available properties are 'keys
- keys -> The provided parameters for template language function 'concat' are invalid. Either all or none of the parameters must be an array.
- keys.key1
- keys.primaryKey
- keys[0]

All of which have failed. I tried putting an `output` at the end of the file but outputting keys just seems to output no value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it turns out the structure of the object returned from listKeys is an array of keys which looks like

```
[
  { "keyName":"key1", "permissions":"Full", "value":"keyvalue1"},
  { "keyName":"key2", "permissions":"Full", "value":"keyvalue2"}
]
```

So the correct solution to getting the value out was to do `keys[0].value`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the listKeys() function

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-template-functions/#listkeys

Comment: I did use listKeys but there doesn't seem to be any documentation on what gets returned by that when used against azure storage. It seems to be some structure but I don't know what or how to get the textual representation of the key for use in concat.

Comment: It returns a based64 encoded string that represents the primary (or secondary) storage key for the account.  If you take a look at this template: https://github.com/rjmax/ArmExamples/blob/master/listKeysSample.json and deploy that you can see the output.  Will look something like this: 3mI6Qg6+TtZ3+aDp/AWlft78UuW7MLFOdR6pcpYHBj0/IQMWNRJU55QPB5bmNgVIIs7V79bNTrnlywujsTXqsw==

Comment: In point of fact, the listKeys function returns a "keys" object, not a base 64 string. That "keys" object is difficult to find documentation regarding.