# Azure App Service Web App Application Logging to Table Storage

Tags: azure, web-applications, diagnostics

In the Classic Portal, web apps can be configured to write Application Logging to Table Storage. In the New Portal, only File System and Blob Storage are options. Can still configure and manage via the Classic Portal for now, however the Classic Portal displays the following "Web apps will soon be available only in the new portal." Will Table Storage no longer be an option? What if already configured that way? Is there a PS cmdlet to manage this?

Comment: did you check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36006676/why-cant-configure-azure-diagnostics-to-use-azure-table-storage-via-new-azure-p) - it seems that logging into a Azure Storage Table is an anti-pattern