# Dynamically retrieving azure storage account key in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-management-api, azure-rm-template

I am trying to automate creating an API Connection for a storage account in Azure using Resource Manager templates.

I am using the `listKeys` method in ARM to retrieve the access key of the storage account. I went through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225678/arm-how-can-i-get-the-access-key-from-a-storage-account-to-use-in-appsettings) and it is not working for me.
When I use the method in the `outputs` section of the template, it is working fine and successfully retrieving and displaying the access key.

`"outputs": {
    "listKeysOutput": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storagename')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value]"
    }
  }`

However, when I try to use the same function inside a connection resource (as shown below), the template executes without any error. But on accessing the API Connection from the Azure portal, it says 'parameter is missing'.

`"parameterValues": {
          "accesskey": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storagename')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value]",
          "accountName": "[parameters('storagename')]"
        }`

[image]

[image]

Am I missing something here? Or the output of listKeys is not being accepted by the 'accesskey' property?

Comment: Could you try to use this rest API（https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt163589.aspx ）?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar experience a few months ago, and resolved it by using a connection string directly in my code and then passing the connection string into the connections. The value looked like this:

```
[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',  variables('storageConfigs')[0].name,';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/',  variables('storageConfigs')[0].name), variables('defaultStorageApiVersion')).key1)]
```

I used a storage config object as an input, so that's why it looks like above you could replace `variables('storageConfigs')[0].name` with whatever name or variable function you use in your code. Looks like above it may be `storagename`

Answer (score 0):

Two things that might be causing the issue:

1. Ensure the API Connection has a dependency on the storage account
2. Capitalise the key in "accessKey" (some things in templates are case sensitive)

Answer (score 0):

@Naren, I recommend you can use this API function to get your Storage Key

> POST
>   `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{accountName}/listKeys?api-version={api-version}`

You could get the same result as the template.

```
    {
  “keys”: [
    {
      “keyName”: “key1”,
      “value”: "key1Value”,
      “permissions”: “FULL”
    },
    {
      “keyName”: “key2”,
      “value”: "key2Value”,
      “permissions”: “FULL”
    },
  ]
}
```

Just for your reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt163589.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Dependency is indeed a requirement so that the storage account is already created before the deployment of the api connection is initiated.

The problem with the OP template code is the use of `accesskey` while the correct parameter name is `accessKey` (Note the capital K) for an Azure Blob api connection resource.

For anyone who struggles with the lack of documentation for the required parameters of API Connection resources - initiate this API Call:

`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<YOUR SUBSCRIPTION ID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/<YOUR LOCATION>/managedApis/<API TYPE>?api-version=2016-06-01`

The `<API TYPE>` should be the api type of the connection to check for example `azureblob`, `azurequeues` or `documentdb`.

A description of all the expected parameters is returned along side other descriptive information for that resource.