# ARM - How can I get the access key from a storage account to use in sql server audit settings later in the template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, azure-rm-template, azure-automation, azure-sql-server

unable to fetch single access key value from array,
i followed this reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/50407157/11191182

```
"storageAccountAccessKey": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('StorageAccountName')), '2017-10-01').key]",
```

**Error**

The 
language expression property 'key1' doesn't exist, available properties are 'keys'.'",

Comment: try `.keys[0]`, it depends on which API version you use.

Comment: I added this "storageAccountAccessKey": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('StorageAccountName')), '2017-10-01').keys[0]]",
but it throws error like { The 'parameters.properties.storageAccountAccessKey' segment in the url is invalid }     
I use apiVersion - 2017-10-01

Comment: Hi @prachi sawant Did you tried `.keys[0].value`, how did it go?

Answer (score 0):

.key1 is an old version of the function listKeys. The syntax now is `.keys[0].value`.

```
 "StorageAccount": "[Concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',variables('StorageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('StorageAccountName')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value)]"
```

Update:
For .key1 syntax you can try using the older version api (2015-05-01-preview). Please refer to below example:

`"accessKey": "[listKeys(variables('storageAccountid'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1]"`

For more information please refer to blog [Retrieve Azure Storage Key in ARM Script](http://samcogan.com/retrieve-azure-storage-key-in-arm-script/)

Comment: Ahh, I forgot about the `.value` bit, yes that should do it.  I'm also against using floating versions for these calls, since you could get future versions of the API which are incompatible (so `.keys[0].value` becomes `.primaryKey` or something), the last thing I want to do is have a template stop working without any changes.

Comment: yes I tried that one it's perfectly working but if want to pass key1 or primarykey instead of keys[0].value then its fails

Comment: Hi @prachisawant if you want to use key1, you need to use the older version of api `2015-05-01-preview`

Comment: Hi @prachisawant Did you specify an older version of api  according above update.  Please [accept above answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it answers your question.